# MYSQL error: Can't create database 'publications'; database exists

Tags: mysql, xampp

I run this command in mysql:

```
mysql > show databases;
```

My database called `publications` is there so I want to use it:

```
mysql > USE publications
```

But I get an error:

```
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'publications'
mysql > CREATE DATABASE publications;
ERROR 1007 (HY000): Can't create database 'publications'; database exists
```

Have I corrupted something?  It is on XAMPP on thumb drive.  What does this error mean?

Comment: Have you checked the spellings? Or tried phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may not have permissions. open up the mysql database, and double check that mysql.db table has the user you are logged in as set up to read, write, etc.. as appropriate. after changing permissions, don't forget to FLUSH PRIVILEGES

Comment: All spellings were correct, I just restarted MySQL & Apache. It allowed me to view via phpMyAdmin, and now CMD too. Very strange, thanks anyway though guys for speedy replies!

Comment: Restarting the mysqld causes the permissions tables to be reloaded. If these are amended via direct DML (INSERT/UPDATE) rather than via GRANT the revised permissions are not applied automatically until the tables are reloaded.